# How to call a JavaScript method for a particular button event using C#

Tags: javascript, html, c#-4.0

I was given a task to automate the validation of content in a web page which has "from airport" and "to airport" text fields along with a `SearchFlights` button. After clicking on the `SearchFlights` button, I get the search results, and I need to compare these results with my expected values.

I am using C# with HTML DOM programming to set the text in text fields and also to click on the `SearchFlights` button.

Now, how do I capture the event (e.g. `documentcompleted`) and save those results so that I can compare them with the expected records? The button I have in that web apge looks like below:

```
<a tabIndex="5" class="searchRht" id="searchBtn" onclick="sF();SearchFlights();return false;" href="" />
```

Once I click on the button, the page refreshes, and a message comes up, saying "loading the Flight Schedules," and after that it displays the results. It looks like the `onclick` method has two function calls: `sF()` and `SearchFlights()`.

I am not sure how I can capture the events and the information returned by that web page.

Below is the code used for clikcing on the button

```
doc = webBrowser1.Document;
btnElem = doc.GetElementById(streleid);
if (btnElem != null)
{
    btnElem.RaiseEvent("onclick");//click on serach button
    btnElem.RaiseEvent("sF()"); //error comes here
    Application.DoEvents();  // this will load the browser document again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MultipleFunction.aspx.cs" Inherits="MultiCust_MultipleFunction" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Execute Multiple function with a Button</title>
</head>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ShowMessage()
{
    alert("Hi");
}


</script>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code behind which achieves what you are looking for.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class MultiCust_MultipleFunction : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "ShowMessage()");
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Zaq");
    }
}
```